# Wordpress redirect to a remote url

Tags: wordpress

I have two domain on separate hosting. On the first I can setup a.mydomain1.com. On the second I can istall wordpress as www.mydomain2.com/wordpress. Now I found a plugin for reidirect to an external website.

My goal is to show wordpress site on a.mydomain1.com. How I have to configure the record in the admin panel of first domain?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is very unclear. And so is your grammer. You want to shwo the wp of `www.mydomain2.com/wordpress` on `a.mydomain1.com`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [WordPress Multisite.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite)
WordPress includes new multisite features, meaning that it can run many blogs, even with their own separate domains, on one WordPress installation.

Comment: I do not know these hosted on different servers

Comment: first line of the question suggests it. But it is vague